Keep populated duplicate rows while removing those with NULL field
I have a dataframe in Python with 3 columns with some duplicate rows. Within the duplicate rows, all fields are the same except for one (which is null).
Example data:



ID
Country
Trades




P11
France
5


P12
Germany
3


P13
UK
7


P13
NULL
7


P14
Croatia
13


P15
USA
5


P15
NULL
5


P16
UK
2


P16
NULL
2



I want to remove the duplicate that contain the NULL value, while keeping the one that has no NULLs in the 'Country' column. Note: it is not only the top duplicate row that has the data while the bottom contains the NULL, sometimes this inverses (top duplicate contains the NULL while bottom duplicate has the country data).
Hoping to clean dataframe down to get this:



ID
Country
Trades




P11
France
5


P12
Germany
3


P13
UK
7


P14
Croatia
13


P15
USA
5


P16
UK
2



Where the duplicates have been removed with no data loss (in the Country column).
Many thanks in advance you legends!

Hi, welcome to SO! With your example, doesn't that simply mean: drop all NaN values in "Country"? I.e., df.dropna(subset='Country'), chaining .reset_index(drop=True) if you want a clean index.

What happens if you have an ID with several non-NA countries?

Hey thanks for your input - no that does not work as I also have a bunch of records that are not duplicates which also have missing Country data (should have included some of those in my question example table) and which I need to keep. So the answer provided by Fernando is actually the way forward as that only drops the duplicate rows with missing Country data :)

Hello and welcome vegeratian_python.
Here's an example of how to solve it:
# Sort by 'Country' and put NAs always first
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='Country', na_position='last')

# Drop duplicates keeping the last occurrence
df_cleaned = df_sorted.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], keep='last')

print(df_cleaned)

